# Testing Angular Controller with 'AS'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I would like to testing my controller, i have used 'controller as' in the app, now i am sh*ting myself over testing.

Controller: (half of my controller)

```
(function(){
    angular.module('donateApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', mainCtrl);

    mainCtrl.$inject = ['donateFactory', 'donateService', '$location'];

    function mainCtrl(donateFactory, donateService, $location){
      var vm = this,
        checked = false;

      vm.submitted = false;
      vm.submitingForm = false;
      vm.amounts = [
        5, 10, 25, 50, 100
      ];
      vm.regions = donateService.getRegion();
      vm.states = donateService.getStates();
```

Testing:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('donateApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl as ctrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });

    $scope.ctrl = MainCtrl;
  }));

  it('Expect the form start with submitted as false', function () {
    expect(MainCtrl.ctrl.submitted).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

Error message i am getting:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'MainCtrl.ctrl')
>           at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/spec/controllers/main.js:22

I know it must be a small fix to make  it work... anyone can help?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Why would you expect `MainCtrl.ctrl` to be defined? Either `MainCtrl.submitted` or `scope.ctrl.submitted` should be all you need. Also, you don't need to assign `$scope.ctrl = MainCtrl` (and I assumed you meant `scope.ctrl` as `$scope` isn't defined); `$controller` does that for you automatically when you use the *controller as* syntax

Comment: @Phil i stealing that idea from some googling... which must be incorrect then... thanks mate i give it a try.

Comment: Reference documentation here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover it...

```
var MainCtrl, scope;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('donateApp');

    inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl as ctrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    });
});

it('publishes the controller on the scope as ctrl', function() {
    // you don't need this test, it's just to show you that
    // scope.ctrl is set correctly when using the "controller as" syntax
    expect(scope.ctrl).toBe(MainCtrl);
});

it('Expect the form start with submitted as false', function() {
    expect(MainCtrl.submitted).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: believe or not... this still doesn't work i vote you up anyhow phil, thanks for the helping :)

Comment: @bluebill1049 hehe, that's what I get for not testing it myself :) What happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'MainCtrl.submitted')
     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/spec/controllers/main.js:24

Comment: @bluebill1049 that's odd. `MainCtrl` should indeed be defined. I just did a quick test locally and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks mate, if you reckon this is correct answer i will give the tick, cause this may help others, i will do some debug see what's going on... Plus + Thank you very much :)

Comment: @bluebill1049 well, I'd like to make sure it works for you first. Can you update your question with the full test spec?

Comment: Phil problem solved ng-message wasn't included in the karam-config! your solution works!!!

Comment: @bluebill1049 nice work. I recommend using your build tool (gulp, grunt, whatever) to inject all the necessary files into the karma config. Saves having to keep on top of it manually.